# Monit not invoking python script <--> OS is CentOS

Tags: python-3.x, monit

Monit not invoking python script <--> OS is CentOS.  first line in python script is "#!/usr/bin/env python3"  when i tried to invoke python script from my terminal its working but monit is not able to trigger the script.

I tried to call python script from shell script in monit but no luck. even i tried adding PATH variable as second line to shell script.
any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please put as code the detial from your configuration.

Comment: You have an issue with the "check program" or the exec action ?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with PATH environmental variable, like cron, monit is only taking subset of values from PATH variable instead of all values. So after explictly adding $PATH variable after shell interpreter, issue got resolved